# Clarification on a linear algebra theorem.

Tags: linear-algebra

> A finite set $S = \{v_1,v_2,..,v_n\}$ of vectors in $V$ is a basis for $V$ iff 
>   $$V = \langle v_1 \rangle\oplus \langle v_2 \rangle \cdots \oplus \langle v_n \rangle$$

This is probably a very dumb question. I am just wondering what $\langle v_1 \rangle\oplus \langle v_2 \rangle \cdots \oplus \langle v_n \rangle$ means. I am assuming that it is essentially Span($S$).

Comment: $\oplus$ means direct sum and $\langle v_1\rangle$ means $\text{Span}(v_1)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We call this an *internal direct sum*. This notation actually includes the notions of both span and linear independence (notice that by definition, both need to be present for $S$ to be a basis).

If linear combinations were all that was being discussed, one could represent $\text{Span}{(S)}$ as, $$\text{Span}{(S)}=\left<v_1\right>+\left<v_2\right>+\ldots +\left<v_n\right>.$$

Instead, the idea of an internal direct sum is that

$V=A\oplus B$ iff $V=A+B$ and $A\cap B=\{\mathbf{0}\}$

Which is much stronger (and addresses linear independence when your summands are $\left<v_i\right>$).